# How to make different length codes for observation equal by adding zeros in R?

Tags: r, database, database-design

I have observations on different families as given by variable `folio`:

```
Folio

1. 10
2. 10
3. 30
4. 30
.
.
.
828. 7110
829. 7130
.
.
.
11841. 107570
11842. 107580
11843. 107590
```

However, as I have other databases with a different format, I need to add zeros to be able to have six digit codes for all observations so they look this way:

```
1. 000010
2. 000010
3. 000030
4. 000030
.
.
.
828. 007110
829. 007130
.
.
.
11841. 107570
11842. 107580
11843. 107590
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

This works: `Folio <- sprintf("%06d",Folio)`

Answer (score 1):

Using the awesome library *stringr*:

```
library(stringr)
str_pad(folio, width = 6, side = c("left"), pad = "0")
```